# How to interact with an REST API returning json using PHP?

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I've been assigned my first project as a junior web developer at my first real gig.

The task is pretty much to get data from a REST API returning JSON, and convert it into products in the CMS we're using.

How do I professionally interact with an API? Do I simply use curl? It seems so naked and "building from ground up". Is there any libraires, techniques that professional developer uses?

Comment: You can make a try http://phphttpclient.com/#json

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl. You can use file_get_content too

If the API will send back only json, you can use

```
$json = file_get_contents('url_here'); 
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

The variable `$object` will contain the data

Comment: curl is much faster than file_get_contents, for 2 reasons: 1: curl supports compressed transfer (gzip and deflate), file_get_contents doesn't. 2: curl stops reading once the `content-length` header's number of bytes have been read, while file_get_contents stall until the target server closes the connection, which can be much faster, some servers keep the connection open for several seconds past end of transfer. thus curl should be used.